# Lua ternary operator - multiple variables

Tags: lua, ternary-operator

Say I want to assign two values to two variables if a certain condition is true, and two different values if said condition is false. I would assume it would be done like this:

```
a, b = 4 > 5 and 1, 2 or 3, 4
```

However this assigns a to be false, and b to be 2.
If we have:

```
a, b = 4 < 5 and 1, 2 or 3, 4
```

This correctly assigns a to be 1 and b to be 2.

What am I missing here, how can I get the "ternary operator" to work as I expect?

Comment: Ternary operator doesn't work with tuples of values, only with single values.  But you can work with arrays: `a, b = unpack(4 > 5 and {1,2} or {3,4})`

Comment: The usual "ternary operator" (so called because it takes three operands) is of the form `expr1 ? expr2 : expr3`. It's also called the "conditional operator". Lua has no such operator.

Comment: @KeithThompson `x and y or z` is equivalent as long as `y` is not false or nil (which isn't usually the case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing that Lua's `and` and `or` are short-cutting and commas are lower in the hierarchy. Basically what happens here is that first `4 > 5 and 1` is evaluated to `false` and `2 or 3` is evaluated to `2`, the `4` is ignored. In the second case `4 < 5` is `true`, thus `4 < 5 and 1` is `1`, the rest stays as it is.

As Egor Skriptunoff suggested you can do

```
a, b = unpack(4 > 5 and {1,2} or {3,4})
```

instead.

Comment: This merely explains why it is behaving like that. It doesn't provide a solution.

Comment: Yes, that is right. My Lua got a bit rusty over the years so I had to poke around a bit to find the same solution as given in the comments.

Comment: Just as a side-note: Using a normal `if ... then else end` construct here would be far more efficient, if that's of any concern.